# How to get value with mouse event drag

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qscrollarea

I have in my UI one `QScrollArea` with an image, and I want to get some value when I click on the image.

Being more explict, I need to change the brightness of an image, and I will get the value with the mouse. I already see the `MouseMoveEvent` but I don't know how to use it.

If I get the position of the mouse when I click and drag, I can extract one value to change the bright of my image, that I know. I just don't know how I will get the position.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Ps.: My `QScrollArea` was created on `Design`, so I don't have any code writed by me with the specifications of the `QScrollArea`.

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't have anything of this, I've tried to put a QScrollBar inside of the QSrollArea and maybe when I scroll the mouse then the image will change. I can do this, but it's not what I want, cause the scrollBar appears all the time and only works when i click on the ScrollBar, so I don't have any code to show, sorry :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you need is in the `QMouseEvent` object that is sent to the `mouseMoveEvent` handler of your widget.

[QMouseEvent::buttons()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#buttons)
[QMouseEvent::pos()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#pos)

A simple way to do what you're after is to change the brightness of the image whenever you receive a "mouse movement event" and the `QMouseEvent` object reports a button down (this means the user is moving the mouse while holding down a button).

```
void MyWidget::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event )
{
    if ( event->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        // Keep the clicking position in some private member of type 'QPoint.'

        m_lastClickPosition = event->pos();
    }
}


void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* event )
{
    // The user is moving the cursor.
    // See if the user is pressing down the left mouse button.

    if ( event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        const int deltaX = event->pos().x() - m_lastClickPosition.x();
        if ( deltaX > 0 )
        {
            // The user is moving the cursor to the RIGHT.
            // ...
        }
        else if ( deltaX < 0 ) // This second IF is necessary in case the movement was all vertical.
        {
            // The user is moving the cursor to the LEFT.
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found yesterday how to get the mouse position how i wanted, pretty looks like that. So, that should work two, thanks anyway.

Comment: Hello. You can answer your own questions here in SO, so next time you can write an answer for yourself and choose that as the solution. It seems to be an encouraged practice. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

there is a small correction . when i programmed like this i was getting the movements a liitle jerky . so i tried to modified the code and now working perfect .
heres how i changed

```
   const int deltaX = event->scenePos().x() - m_lastClickPosition.x();
    if ( deltaX > 10 )// to the right
    {
       moveBy(10,0);
       m_lastClickPosition = event->scenePos();
    }
    else if ( deltaX <-10 )
    {
        moveBy(-10,0);
        m_lastClickPosition = event->scenePos();
    }
```